# MVC in frontend, too many Controllers doing almost the same thing?

Tags: model-view-controller, structure, frontend, web-frontend

**STRUCUTRE**

The following MVC is an example but explains the problem I am facing.

**Models**

```
class Model.User

    create: (data) ->
        $.post '/public/account/create', data
```

**Views**

```
class View.User

    disableButton: ->
        $('.button').disable()

    disableAnotherButtonAndFade: ->
        $('.button2').disable()
        $('form').fadeOut()
```

**Controllers**

```
class Controller.User

    register: ->
        model.create {username: 'YamiOdymel', password: 'test123'}

        view.disableButton()


    # Another controller but does almost the same thing as the previous one
    anotherRegister: ->

        model.create {username: 'YamiOdymel', password: 'test123'}

        view.disableAnotherButtonAndFade()
        view.doSomethingOther()
```

---

**PROBLEM**

1. The controllers are calling the **same model**, but **different View callbacks**, for this situation I have to create more Controllers to deal with the different View callbacks.
2. The callbacks are different **since a component might appear in the other pages**

   For example, a "Like button" might appeared in a post or a comment even an user's profile,

   **they are all "Like button" but different View feedbacks**, and the **Models are different** (*where to get the post id, comment id, user id*).

I have no idea how do I exactly structure my MVC flow at the frontend,

a **MVC per page** (*profile, post, homepage*)? or a **MVC per "module"** (*User, Like, Comment*) or even **a MVC per component**?

How do I solve the problem about too many controllers?

I have read some other structures like: **Flux**, **Vuex**.

But **it's not so friendly for Server-Side Render** web application (I'm using SSR).